# Invalid argument: attachments in MailApp

Tags: google-apps-script

I m trying to automate sending of mail with an attachment of a document that is fetched from the drive

```
 var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById('link of drive folder');
  var file = DriveApp.getFilesByName('name of doc');

  MailApp.sendEmail({
    to: to_email,
    cc: cc_email,
    subject: "Document",
    attachments: [file],
    body: "Requires HTML",
    htmlBody: body
  });
```

error : Invalid argument: attachments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see in the official documentation, [DriveApp.getFilesByName](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#getfilesbynamename) returns a [FileIterator](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file-iterator.html). This is not a valid attachment.

To get a file of that name, you would have to chain the method [next()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file-iterator.html#next()). So you would have to change this:

```
var file = DriveApp.getFilesByName('name of doc');
```

To this:

```
var file = DriveApp.getFilesByName('name of doc').next();
```

The reason behind this is that you can have many files with the same name in your Drive, so if you want to send a specific file you might prefer using [getFileById](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#getFileById(String)), which looks for a file with a specific id (id's are unique).

If what you want to do is to send all files that share the same name, you can modify your code like this:

```
var files = DriveApp.getFilesByName(file_name);
var attachments = []
while (files.hasNext()) {
  var file = files.next();
  attachments.push(file);
}
MailApp.sendEmail({
  to: to_email,
  cc: cc_email,
  subject: "Document",
  attachments: attachments,
  htmlBody: body
});
```

Also, I hope the `body` variable in this line is defined in some part of the code you have omitted. Otherwise you will get another error there:

```
htmlBody: body
```

I hope this helps you.

Comment: It works fine now after addition of next() , thank you !